# The ghosts of my stories would be explainable by physics and quantum physics

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, ghosts

The ghost of my stories would be explainable by quantum and regular physics.
After reflexion about my ghosts, I decided to put it like this :

They are composed of higgs boson and fermions that are forced into a shape by a magnetic or electromagnetic field.The pair of particles is able to turn into their condensate version at will by the ghost but with straining effort. It would explain why they can only appear and interact in the physical world for short periods at a time.

However, I know that higgs bosons decay into other particles almost immediately after their creation and I don't know to explain their longer shelf-life in their pairing with fermions.
I want to give a explanation that seem « authentic », well-developed in both scientific and layman terms. Or, could this be already more concise to explain in scientific terms only ?

Comment: (1) *"Which combination?* I suggest the forty-second one, or maybe variation delta of the fifty-seventh one. (2) *"I wonder if it is possible?"* Of course it is. In your story you are the omnipotent creator and demiurge; your will is law, whatever you say goes. Whether the readers will like it or not is a different problem. (3) *"What in metaphysics?"* I'm afraid that you have a mistaken idea about what metaphysics is. Metaphysics is a (very wide) field of enquiry; it is most definitely not *one* universally agreed body of knowledge from which you can pick a paragraph.

Comment: I am not a physicist. My interest in string theory and physics in general is at the hobby level. My understanding of string theory is that is really a class of solutions with more variations than there are grains of sand on all the beaches in the world. Already, my mind is totally blown. Add the several options for mirror matter and it gets really messy. This seems like hand waving about hand waving about hand waving. In other words, this is a question about everything and nothing. I am powerless to answer.

Comment: In other words, show us your research into the world that you are trying to create. Moreover, tell us about that world and what you are trying to achieve. Please read-up in the [help] about our guidelines. Also see definition of [Hand Waving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving).

Comment: The trouble with the recent edit is that the anti-particle of the Higgs Boson, is a Higgs Boson. Not sure what you are asking here. See[ particle types, [Bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles#Bosons)

Answer (score 1):

**Use all of them.**

> "So what did he say?"
>
> Tim sucked on his bad tooth and looked pensive.  "He said the universe is
> made of strings."   He moved a finger through the air, drawing a string, or maybe a ghost. "And ghosts are stringy."
>
> Woomer nodded at this.  "Stringy.  That explains a lot.  What else?"
>
> "Ghosts are made of mere matter.  Mere matter.  And..."  Tim looked a
> little uncomfortable.  "They got Higgs bosoms."
>
> Woomer's eyebrows went up.  "All of em?"  Tim nodded.  "Even the
> stringy ones?  Stringy dude ghosts?"
>
> Tim put away the cards and motioned with his chin.  "Let's go, Wooms.
> We got what we're gonna get."

Those theories you list are funky and rareified.  Some of your readers may have heard of them and maybe 0.01% will understand a little bit.  Have your characters not understand either.  Someone in your world understands, though, and maybe tried to explain.  It was not much help.  That guy is generally not much help.